# Ruby Class Method with Each Method : newbie learning through Bloc

Tags: ruby, methods

I am currently a student through Bloc, and am struggling with Class Methods.  I am working through the lesson on the Each Method.  The first part of the instructions are:

> Let's mix this new each trick with some of the `Class` concepts we've been practicing. Create an `ArrayModifier` class. It should take an array as an argument to its `initialize` function, and have one instance method:
>
> - `exclaim` -- Loops through the array and returns a new array of each element with an exclamation mark added.

Here is what I am coming up with so far, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  I particularly do not understand initialize and how to use it properly.

```
class ArrayModifier

  attr_accessor :array

  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
  end

  def exclaim
    @array.each do |i|
      puts i + "!"
    end
    @array
  end

end
```

Comment: "Returns" is ambiguous. In your code  attempt, you `puts` every element, rather than `return`ing them. Would be good to know just what the question asked for.

Comment: What is Bloc?    ..............

Comment: @sawa I think [it is this](https://www.bloc.io/)

Comment: I think you're getting downvotes and flags because this is a such a primitively-simple question.  It lacks a demonstration of even some of the most-basic foundations of the language.  However that close voting goes, I think you should take what answers you've gotten and consider how you could have done this research on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of initialize is correct. All it must do is capture and save the array that is sent in. If you wanted to be fancy, you may write

```
def initialize( arr )
  raise ArgumentError unless arr.is_a?(Array)
  @array = arr
end
```

Since, after all, if we didn't pass in an actual array, then all of the forthcoming things will fail. You'll see this pattern as you get into more advanced programming.

But `puts` is not going to "return" things, only "print" them out, leaving the actual return value `@array` to be the same as before.

You are learning `each`, but when you read the docs on that method, you'll see that it has 'cousins' which act similarly. I think in this case you wanted to use `map`:

```
def exclaim
  @array.map do |i|
    "#{i}!"
  end
end
```

This takes every element in the array, interpolates it into a string which has a suffix with the character "!"  [String interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) is nil-safe, which makes it a best practice for conciseness.  Since this array-modification is the only *expression* in the method, it is the `return` result of the method.

The `irb` debugger will print the result of `.exclaim` to the screen, but other Ruby code would capture this `return` as a ruby object, and be able to act on it further.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the sentence:

> Loops through the array and returns a new array of each element with an exclamation mark added.

It does not ask you to print each element of array. It asks you to return a "new" array with all element added an exclamation mark.

```
class ArrayModifier

  attr_accessor :array

  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
  end

  def exclaim
    new_array = []
    @array.each do |i|
      new_array << i.to_s + "!"
    end
    new_array
  end
end
```

A better alternative of the exclaim method:

```
def exclaim
  @array.map{|e| "#{e}!"}
end
```